# Shift + 3 gives pound instead of hash after Update

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters, 17.10

I updated Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. After update, my keyboard layout changed automatically. Now instead of getting hash on pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, I am getting the £ symbol. I cannot even find keyboard layout settings in GNOME Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a terminal window run `setxkbmap us` and restart the session. It may work without restarting too. That would set your keyboard layout to US English.

Comment: Thanks, please accept the answer and vote it up if the issue has been resolved.

Comment: I did upvote it, but as my reputation is low, it won't be displayed!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a keyboard layout through the settings menu, under Region & Language. Click the '+' sign to add a new layout.

[image: Input sources]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one I just found in a live boot environment. From the terminal run: `gkbd-keyboard-display` and see if you can set it from there - not sure if this one will work but `setxkbmap us` definitely worked for me (after I deliberately broke it) in a live boot environment.